# Resize 3 different pictures proportionally with form #

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I have three pictures that are connected and it seems like one picture. I use this because in some situations I have to change color of some of there pictures, but that is not important.
How can I group these pictures, and what to do more that they seems like one picture when is form resized..
I tried a lot of that, but problem is because pictures are different sizes..
Any suggestions, thanks in advance...

Comment: A screenshot of what you're describing would probably help. Generally, you'd probably need to look into the `Anchor` or `Dock` properties and/or using a `TableLayoutPanel` container.

Comment: You could put the three parts into 3 pictureboxes with sizemode zoom and put those into a TableLayoutPanelwith proportional sizing. But your desctiption is not clear enough to know, or I'm afraif to code.